# How can I leverage a dynamic Data Flow in Azure Data Factory to map lookup tables based on a config file?

Tags: dynamic, azure-pipelines, config, azure-data-factory

I am attempting to create a pipeline that accepts values from a config file (JSON) in an attempt to build a source query, lookup logic, and destination sink based on the values from the file.

An example of an object from the config file would look something like this:

```
 {
    /*Destination Table fields */
    "destTableName": "DimTable1",
    "destTableNaturalKey": "ClientKey, ClientNaturalKey",
    "destTableSchema": "dbo",
    /*Source Table fields */
    "sourcePullFields": "ClientKey, ClientNaturalKey",
    "sourcePullFilters": "WHERE ISNULL(ClientNaturalKey,'') <> ''",
    "sourceTableName": "ClientDataStaged",
    "sourceTableSchema": "stg"

  }
```

The pipeline would identify the number of items within the config (for each) that need to be checked for new data, in a basic pipeline like this:

[Pipeline pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGSm.png)

I would then pass these values into the data flow, from the ADF Pipeline:
[ADF Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYFLn.png)

And build the source pull and lookup values within the Data flow expressions with something like this:

```
concat('SELECT DISTINCT ', $sourcePullFields, ' FROM ', $sourceTableSchema, '.', $sourceTableName, ' ', $sourcePullFilters)
```

When I am within the data flow, and pass the same config values within the debug settings, I can correctly view projections and step through the data flow correctly. It is when I execute the data flow from the pipeline that I get errors.

As a second attempt, I simply passed through the source query within the config:

```
{
    "destQuery": "SELECT Hashbytes('MD5', (cast(ClientKey as varchar(5)) + ClientNaturalKey)) AS DestHashVal FROM dbo.DimTable1",
    "sourceQuery": "SELECT DISTINCT ClientKey, ClientNaturalKey, Hashbytes('MD5', ( Cast(SchoolKey AS VARCHAR(5)) + ClientNaturalKey )) AS SourceHashVal FROM stg.ClientNaturalKey WHERE Isnull(ClientNaturalKey, '') <> ''"
  }
```

I had intended to use the md5 function within the data flow expressions, but at this point I simply want to:

1. Define a source query, whether it be via a SQL statement or built from variables
2. Define a lookup query, whether it be via a SQL statement or built from variables
3. Have the ability to compare a Hashed value(s) from source to the lookup (destination table)
4. If the lookup returns no match on the hash, load the values

[ADF Data Flow Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzbr8.png)

Ideally I am not defining the SQL statement directly.. it just feels less intelligent. Regardless, this is to prevent migrating ~50 DFTs from SSIS to a few pipelines and a single data flow that can handle the dynamacy. Since the process has been working within the confines of the data flow, I have been messing with passing in the parameters in different ways, removing quotes, unsure of what the string interpolation is doing.. etc.

Comment: Did you try hand-coding the values as default values in your data flow parameters to make sure that the data flow is properly interpreting your syntax first? Pipelines and Data Flows interpret strings differently, so if you can, try using Data Flow expressions in parameters. Also, double quotes " in data flow expressions signal string interpolation. So everything inside the " tells data flows to look for params, fields, expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#string-interpolation

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the follow-up. I have hard-coded the values within the data flow successfully - both with the fully-built SQL query and the multiple variables concat expression logic. My assumption (touched on it lightly above) as you hinted at is that the quotes being passed from the JSON object, plus the string interpolation - I believe something is happening here that appears to be the impediment. That's why I tried - I think to no success - a second iteration I attempted to omit " " characters as I pass the parameters to the data flow:https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYFLn.png

Comment: Commenting here after re-reading my response, want to re-affirm that I have been unsuccessful in passing in the parameters from pipeline to data flow. I am going to try to do it from a table, to confirm my suspicion that the quotation characters from the JSON file are causing the issue @MarkKromerMSFT